# Advice on creating a "popular now" widget that displays daily, or even hourly, popular posts

Tags: wordpress

I've made a widget for my theme that displays the most popular posts on the website, based on a few tutorials.

Currently, this function is run everytime a user views an article:

```
function wpb_set_post_views($postID) {
$count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    $count = 0;
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
}else{
    $count++;
    update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
}
}
```

And the widget loops out the posts via this loop:

```
$popularpost = new WP_Query( array('post_type', array( 'post', 'features', 'reviews', 'podcasts'), 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC'  ) );
                while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();
```

Although this works perfectly for showing the most popular posts of all time, I'm curious as to whether it would be possible to show the most popular posts at the moment, perhaps hourly or daily.

Would this be possible using the methods I'm using at the moment? If not, could anyone suggest alternative ways of solving this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you differentiate between 'all-time' popular posts and 'in-the-last-hour' popular posts?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. This is beyond my PHP skills I fear... could we perhaps track the views in two separate variables? Can we reset one every hour? Or every day?